# using stored procedures inside queries SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, business-intelligence, ssrs-2008-r2

I can't succeed using stored procedure inside query in query editor of SSRS

I've structure similar to

```
declare @DateStart datetime
...
exec API_someprocedure
     @DateStart = @DateStart

select * from tTablefromstoredprocedure
```

It always returns error, when I run query it asks DateStart, I enter '20140401' error converting data type varchar to smalldatetime returns, if I enter 20140401 error converting data type int to smalldatetime returns. What should I do?

Comment: To me, that looks like the 4th of January, but the OP means the 1st of April. A more reliable way is to use the following format: `2014-04-01`

Comment: Are you actually executing this from SSRS or just T-SQL?